# what would happen if there were windmills in space?

Tags: nasa, physics

If there was a windmill in space and you spun it, would it spin forever creating infinite energy? or would it somehow slow down or not create energy? if instead of wind you used magnets to spin the turbines would it be able to create energy or..? I have had this question for quite some time now.

Comment: it would slow down because the magnets would cause it to stop

Comment: About the only thing that could save this is a solar wind mill?  Yes!  The blades could be made of solar panels too.

Comment: "spin forever creating infinite energy" questions will be closed in any science-based Stack Exchange site. [Proposals for such inoperable machines have become so common that the United States Patent and Trademark Office (USPTO) has made an official policy of refusing to grant patents for perpetual motion machines without a working model.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion#Patents)

Comment: A spinning thing has some kinetic energy because it's moving, but it doesn't *create* any energy. Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/250165/123208

Answer (score 1):

It would slow down because of 2 things:

- Friction
- and magnetism

The friction part is obvious, as there is air in space and no machine can have 100% efficiency. I think your confused on how windmills produce energy, its not by the blades spinning, its by the magnets/electromagnets slowing it down aka taking energy away from it and making electricity.

Comment: Re, "the magnets slowing it down." That might be confusing to some readers because if there's a steady wind, and if there's a constant demand for electricity, then the "magnets" (i.e., the generator) _do not_ slow it down. It keeps turning at a constant speed. The wind is constantly _doing work_ on the turbine blades, the turbine is constantly doing work on the generator shaft, the generator is constantly providing power to the grid.  "Doing work on the generator shaft" means that the turbine is turning the shaft despite the fact that the generator is "pushing back", resisting the rotation.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes, if you want to edit it, go right ahead